# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null Not working after using window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null sample.aspx:40 sample.aspx 40
 - window.onload                                                         sample.aspx 40
```

I have search to solve this error But I am unable to successful. I found a lot of posting related to this error and every one are suggested to use `Window.onload` But still I could able to solve my issuse.

Here is my Code

```
<script>
         var b4 = document.getElementById('b4'),
          button4 = document.getElementById('set4');
         window.onload = function () {
             button4.onclick = function () {

                 // Update the Button
                 var pause = button4.innerHTML === 'start!';

                 return false;

             }
         };

    </script>
```

So any one  please tell me how to solve this error.

Comment: do you have an element with `id=set4`? - are you waiting for the element to be in the DOM first before running the code?

Comment: Yes I have an element with id=set4. And Yes It is working fine for the other buttons. only for this button it is showing me the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting you variable outside the `onload`. The DOM is not ready so the elements doesnt exist yet. Try putting it inside the load event :

```
     window.onload = function () {
         var b4 = document.getElementById('b4'),
          button4 = document.getElementById('set4');
         button4.onclick = function () {

             // Update the Button
             var pause = button4.innerHTML === 'start!';

             return false;

         }
     };
```

Comment: @user2787300 Is that button added later or it is there on first page load?

Comment: It is there on the page load

Comment: @user2787300 can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: I never Used Fiddle.  and it will be difficult for me to upload it in fiddle.

Comment: @user2787300 Well then, can we atleast see the HTML?

Comment: @user2787300 example of the error [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wb6d/) and here's an example of his solution [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2KLw7/) which should work

Comment: @ ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ No still the same error. I tried as your Suggestion but it is not working.